# Why is textInput.keyboardType nil in textDidChange?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I'm developing a custom keyboard in Swift and I would like to know when the keyboard type changes (to a number or decimal keyboard type for example). I believe this should be done in either `textDidChange` or `textWillChange`. This method receives a `UITextInput` which has a property `keyboardType`. But when this method is called, that property seems to always be `nil` because it never runs the following code, even after I have entered a different input type (number).

```
override func textDidChange(textInput: UITextInput) {
    if let inputType = textInput.keyboardType {
        //never gets here
        deleteKeyboardButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you must get the `UITextDocumentProxy` and use its `keyboardType` property, not the `textInput`'s property.

```
var proxy = self.textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy
if proxy.keyboardType == UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress {
    //add code here to display email input keyboard
}
```